# How to check whether shared preferences is null or not in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my apps for login and logout functionality, I am checking whether the shared preferences is null or not when activity starts, but I am still getting a NullPointerException.

Here is my code for HomeActivity.java:

```
// Username And Password Editbox
String eusername;
String epassword;

// Shared Preferences String declaration
String spusername;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    SharedPreferences spreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    spusername=spreferences.getString("spusername","");

    if(!spusername.equals(""))
    {   
        Log.e("Spusername not null","-->"+spusername);
    }
    if(spusername==null)
    {
        Log.e("Spusername null","-->"+spusername);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your exception log details

Comment: which statement throws the null pointer exception?

Comment: *cheking the shared preferences is null* Are you referring to the variable `spreferences` that is being null?

Comment: now the null pointer error is gone but one problem is there if spusername is null than still is enter into the if(!spusername.equals(""))
        {   
            Log.e("Spusername not null","-->"+spusername);

        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are giving `eusername` without initializing this variable so getting null pointer exception
So try like this

```
spusername = preferences.getString("spusername", "n/a");

if(spusername!= null && !spusername.equals(""))
    {   
        Log.e("Spusername != null","-->"+spusername);

    }
   else{
               // your code is here
    }
```

Comment: still is enter int the if(spusername!=null)
        {   
            Log.e("Spusername != null","-->"+spusername);
if is null
        } condition

Comment: ya. let me clarify is there pref_string in the spusername or not

Comment: no this is chek when out activity is start if preferences is null  than is display my username and passsword editbox other wise is show SIGNOUT BUTTON FOR login activity

Comment: @AndroidNew : if you remove last if condition and use else instead of if then i think your issue is get solved

Comment: This code will never run into the if block (except if the spusername stored in prefs is the empty string) since spusername will be either "n/a" either the spusername stored in sharedPreferences.

Comment: Answer is incorrect. If 'spusername' is null it will still throw NPE when calling equals(""). Null test should be first.

Answer (score 10):

You have [`contains`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29) method on SharedPreferences.

```
boolean isSpUsernameDefined = spreferences.contains("spusername");
```

Comment: Balls! I need coffee... sorry! Have reverted my downvote - was not thinking at all here! mea culpa... good idea to use `contains` keyword to check if the actual key is there...

Comment: Done sir! Feel invigorated after coffee boost! :)

Answer (score 2):

The method "spreferences.getString("spusername", eusername);" is returning the default value as eusername which is null. Hence it is giving null pointer exception.

Instead eusername, You can try by giving some string value as below.

spreferences.getString("spusername", "");

Answer (score 1):

try as:

```
spusername=spreferences.getString("spusername", "");
```

add default value for spusername if the key is not found in SharedPreferences and now check it for emplty or null  as:

```
spusername=spreferences.getString("spusername", "");

if(!spusername.equals("")){   
     Log.e("Spusername != null","-->"+spusername);
}else{
      // do some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because as you didn't initialize the default value.

```
String eusername;
```

this will always give you null until you didn't save any value into the shared preference.
Just initialize with empty string

```
String eusername = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure you saved some data into Sharedpreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
preferences.putString("appVersion", "1.0");
preferences.putString("appAuthor", "John Doe");
preferences.putString("authorEmail", "test@gmail.com");
preferences.apply();
preferences.commit();
```

Then you need to initialize the SharedPreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then you can use `getAll()` method to get an Array of available Sharedpreferences, then use the `contains` method to do some logics based on your condition.
Here's what I do to log all availables preferences:

```
Log.d("AVAILABLE_PREFS", String.valueOf(preferences.getAll()));
```

Then I can make a condition based on the result I got:

```
if (preferences.contains("appVersion")) {

    if(preferences.getString("appVersion", SETTINGS).equals("1.0")){
         // Do something if TRUE
    }

} else {
   // Do something here if no Preferences found.
}
```